# Why is this happening in my simple HTML example I'm working on

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get familiar with CSS but some of things that are happening seem rather arbitrary.

For example:

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/48yGU/24/

Why is only the first and second divs displayed (`playerinformation and centerad`), but not the third one? I thought divs were stacked vertically unless told otherwise via floats or what have you.

Any suggestions?.

I just want three div, organized horizontally within the middle vertical div called `middle`.

Comment: Adblock software kicking in? Mine does.

Comment: Jesus, disabled adblock and it works. Are you saying the addon detected that keyword in the div and made it invisible. Wow. I hope other people find this question helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Yup, also if some image has "ad" in the filename, then it gets blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is `#rightad` is being removed by Adblock, or an equivalent. That's what's happening for me. If you disable your adblocked, I bet it will show up.

Comment: +1: You got there first! - the -1 vote is a bit harsh though.

Comment: @Kalle: That happens all the time when you step away from the page to check the answer then don't refresh before answering.

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Yup, totally my bad. Changed my vote of course.

Comment: Yes yes, totally my bad. Nice catch on the adblocker!

Answer (score 0):

All worked for me (in Firefox), then installed AdBlock and the #rightad disappeared. Disabled adblock for the page and it reappeared again.

Alternative quick test would be to try your jsfiddle in a different browser and see if its all there.